# Match two columns conditional formatting

Tags: excel

I can't get my Excel problem to work. I have the following table:

[image]

In this instance, I want the fruit in column B filled green if Name is in Lemon(D) or Apple(E). I tried MATCH and VLOOKUP, but I keep getting errors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, as your sample which cell should be `Green`?

Comment: If A is in D or E, B should be green, if not B should be red

Comment: So, with current data `B2` and `B3` would be `Green` and `B4` would be `Red`, right?

Comment: Yes, correct! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> with current data B2 and B3 would be Green and B4 would be Red

Select ColumnB, format (standard) populated cells red and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF(D:E,A1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select green formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.